# a for loop which destroys an original string

Tags: c

I am currently trying to iterate over a string to find the first white space.
I want to copy all of the characters before that white space into a different string.

Here I am coping more of my code: lineArray is global, and is filled in by a different function which I didn't copy.

```
char *lineArray[16];

int startProcesses(int background) {

    int i = 0;
    int var = 0;
    int pid;
    int status;
    int len;
    char copyProcessName[255];

    while(*(lineArray+i) != NULL) {


    len = strlen(lineArray[i]);

    for (var = 0; var < len; ++var) {
        if(lineArray[i][var] != ' ') {
            copyProcessName[var] = lineArray[i][var];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

I know this is not finished and I am missing '\0', but before that I have noticed on debug that after the first time the compiler tries the `copyProcessName[var] = lineArray[i][var];` assignment, the whole string which is in lineArray[i] is destroyed and instead of for example containing `ls -l` it is replaced with `ll - l`.

I will mention a few more thins: 
lineArray is a global variable, I did try using strcpy but it caused the same destruction so this is the reason I chose to implement it, last thing is that I am using ubuntu.

Does anyone have an idea why is doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a complete compilable test case. Also, look up strtok()

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct code? there seems to be no error in this?

Comment: yes, I did try running the code on a different computer but it did the same thing.

Comment: @Steinfeld: This is likely related to how you are allocating memory for `lineArray` and `copyProcessName`. Thus, the actual problem is likely not found in the code you've shown us. Elchonon's suggestion to provide a compilable sample is truly the best suggestion here.

Comment: Perhaps add a write to memory breakpoint to your array to make sure something else isn't trashing it.  Also compile with all warnings on and fix those to make sure you aren't doing anything semi-illegal.

Comment: Where do you allocate memory to the pointers stored in `lineArray`?

Comment: it up there, for some reason I could not cover it with the gray background.

Comment: the pointers are allocated memory by strtok(); which is in the function I stated I did not copy.

Comment: And the feed to `strtok()` is also global/static? Btw: `strtok()` does **not** allocated any memory, but returns references to what it was feed.

Comment: no it is a local buffer, which is filled in by fgets from stdin.

Comment: Make the local buffer static or allocate it on the heap, as it's gone if you leave the function to which it is declared locally.

Comment: @alk, thank you very much, this has worked perfectly. I did think that I could avoid such a problem just by declaring lineArray global, can you please explain with more detail why is that buffer also needed to be declared global?

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently trying to iterate over a string to find the first white space.

Cool.

```
char s[] = "line with spaces";
char *p = strchr(s, ' '); // pointer to the first WS, if you need it
ptrdiff_t n = p - s; // or its position within the string, if that's what you're looking for
```

Comment: hey H2CO3, I tried using various string.h functions. All causing the same destruction of the original array.

Comment: @Steinfeld: Then the problem surely is not in the code that you have shown us

Comment: Then we really need to see a compilable test case.